# How to get the id attribue of specific set of elements in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="celldata-class" id="102108386358" title="celldata_23_01/05/2022"></td>
<td class="celldata-class" id="101660658921" title="celldata_24_01/05/2022"></td>
<td class="celldata-class" id="102081568186" title="celldata_25_01/05/2022"></td>
<td class="celldata-class" id="101995272597" title="celldata_26_01/05/2022"></td>
    </tr>                                                                      
    </table>
```

I am trying to get all ids attribute in all TDS which have class name = celldata-class in jquery.
I already have tried this code

```
 values = "";
            $('.celldata-class').each(function() {
                values =  values + "," +$(this).attr('id')+"*";
           
            });
        
       console.log(values);
    });
```

but the id returns undefined, what is the problem?

Comment: Your solution works. See https://jsfiddle.net/uonmLkgf/11

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the problem in the plugins compatibility I am using, you are right, when use this code without the plugin, it works but when I use this code with the plugin, it not work, thanks once again

Comment: I am using the plugin Jspreadsheet, it seems issue when access ids with this plugins, I have solved the issue by use the class name, it works perfect

Comment: Use this simple code instead: `let values = $('.celldata-class').map((i,x)=>x.id).toArray().join(",")`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the plugin Jspreadsheet, it seems issue when accessing ids with these plugin, I have solved the issue by use the class name instead of id, it works perfect.